# Disable the timeouts on apache httpd and fastcgi

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

A debian lenny server, running apache httpd 2.2.11 and fastcgi, kills requests when they take more than a certain amount of seconds. I want to disable this timeout to enable me to debug an application that is launched using fastcgi.

I've searched in both apache and lighttpd documentation, but couldn't find anything (only options like idle-timeout, that isn't the case here, I think).

Anyone knows how to control this timeout? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want one of the [FastCGI directives](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/q20204/mod_fastcgi.html): FastCGIServer, FastCGIConfig, or FastCgiExternalServer, depending.  `FastCGIConfig` affects all FastCGI applications; the other two are per-application.  You'll want one of these options (check the docs to be sure which is appropriate):

> `-appConnTimeout n` (0 seconds)
>       Unix:  The number of seconds to wait for a connection to the FastCGI
>   application to complete or 0 to
>   indicate a blocking connect() should
>   be used. Blocking connect()s have an
>   OS dependent internal timeout. If the
>   timeout expires, a `SERVER_ERROR`
>   results. For non-zero values, this is
>   the amount of time used in a select()
>   to write to the file descriptor
>   returned by a non-blocking connect().
>   Non-blocking connect()s are
>   troublesome on many platforms. See
>   also -idle-timeout, it produces
>   similar results but in a more portable
>   manner.
>       Windows NT:  TCP based applications work as above. Named pipe
>   based applications (static
>   applications configured without the
>   -port option and dynamic applications) use this value successfully to limit
>   the amount of time to wait for a
>   connection (i.e. it's not
>   "troublesome"). By default, this is 90
>   seconds
>   (`FCGI_NAMED_PIPE_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` in
>   mod_fastcgi.h).
>
> `-idle-timeout n` (30 seconds)
>       The number of seconds of FastCGI application inactivity allowed before
>   the request is aborted and the event
>   is logged (at the error LogLevel). The
>   inactivity timer applies only as long
>   as a connection is pending with the
>   FastCGI application. If a request is
>   queued to an application, but the
>   application doesn't respond (by
>   writing and flushing) within this
>   period, the request will be aborted.
>   If communication is complete with the
>   application but incomplete with the
>   client (the response is buffered), the
>   timeout does not apply.
>
> `-min-server-life n` (30)
>       The minimum number of seconds the application must run for before its
>   restart interval is increased to 600
>   seconds. The server will get 3 tries
>   to run for at least this number of
>   seconds.

Comment: I've already tried that, without success! No matter what I do, the request is killed in 30 seconds.

Comment: which one are you setting it on?  have you tried using `FastCGIConfig -idle-timeout 600` or similar to affect the overall module?

Comment: Well, passing the -idle-timeout (misleading name) directly to the launcher solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache the directive you want is Timeout.  On some distros it defaults to 300 or so.  Many people have started lowering this to mitigate "Slowloris"-type attacks.

```
Timeout 10
```

Should be able to set it right up to 10 minutes, if you want:

```
Timeout 600
```